# Avoid Graph API redirect loops but redirect to slugged URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I've stumbled upon a tricky situation I'm not sure how to solve.

I use the Facebook Graph API to track shares on my web app's articles and display that counter to my users. The API requires that I specify an `og:url` property to know under which URL to aggregate counts.

My URL structure is as follows:

```
.../posts/id/slug
```

The slug is purely cosmetic and optional. If it is later changed (which sometimes happens), I want to ensure:

1. That my users are still redirected to the right page
2. That the share counter isn't reset

To satisfy condition 1, I set up the following redirects:

```
A) .../posts/id            --> .../posts/id/current-slug
B) .../posts/id/wrong-slug --> .../posts/id/current-slug
```

To satisfy condition 2, I pointed my `og:url` to the slugless URL `.../posts/id`, which is invariable.

But of course, this causes a redirect loop for the Facebook grapher, whether the initial URL was correct (case X) or not (case Y).

Case X:

```
Start: .../posts/id/slug
   --> .../posts/id        (Because of og:url)
   --> .../posts/id/slug   (Because of redirect)
   --> (loop)
```

Case Y:

```
Start: .../posts/id/wrong-slug
   --> .../posts/id/correct-slug (Because of redirect)
   --> (back to case 1)
```

Any idea how to solve that problem?

The only solution I see at the moment is to remove redirect A), but it makes the URL much less user/SEO friendly.

Answer (score 2):

There is two things you can try:

First you can use `<link rel="canonical" href=".../posts/id" />` which I believe is valid as og:url **replacement** and should then the Facebook robot should not follow redirection on that one. But I didn't test it and it seems wrong to me.

Second, you could block the redirect for the Facebook og robot on server side so it won't enter in a loop,
or (less elegant) do a redirect in javascript to the slugged url (if needed) that way the robot won't be effected (it does not use javascript)

Personally and if it's possible with your setup, I strongly recommend the **second** solution using the **server side**

Comment: I would disable the redirect for the Facebook bot; look for the strings `facebookexternalhit/1.0`, `facebookexternalhit/1.1` and `Facebot` in the user agent - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#user-agent-whitelisting

Comment: if it works for you don't hesitate to valid the answer

Comment: I'll try this week and let you know. Thanks for the user agent strings, too!

Comment: How exactly are you suppose to do it?